# What is the use of 'Route' in Restangular functions oneUrl() and allUrl()

Tags: angularjs, rest, restangular

That's the signature for `oneUrl` function: `oneUrl(route, url)`
 
And from the documentation:

> **oneUrl(route, url)**: This will create a new Restangular object that is
>   just a pointer to one element with the specified URL.

To me, it seems useless to set `Route` when you are giving a url for the resource. Why does it exist in the argument list? Why is it mandatory? And how can it be used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my use of `oneUrl` I've found the route name is used to build the URL for subsequent `PUT` and `DELETE` operations. For example (pseudo code):

```
// "GET /api/v2/users/3/ HTTP/1.1" 200 184
var user = Restangular.oneUrl('myuser', 'http://localhost:8000/api/v2/users/3').get();
user.name = 'Fred';
// the following uses the route name and not the URL:
// "PUT /api/v2/myuser HTTP/1.1 404 100
user.put();
```

I was surprised by this behavior. I expected `put()` to use the same URL as `get()`; which would be helpful in my case.

My API uses absolute URLs within the JSON payloads to navigate to all related resources and I wanted to use `oneUrl()` to `GET/PUT` instances without recreating the routes in the JS code. But I'm pretty new to Restangular so I might not have the mental model correct.

Comment: Exactly! According to my understanding of REST design, responses should be self descriptive and contain links to other resources as needed. And because of that, `oneUrl` is one of the frequently used methods of Restangular for me!
How about passing the absolute url also for `route`?! Doesn't it fix the problem you mentioned?

Comment: @AlirezaMirian funny I didn't even think of that; it seemed "wrong"... but it ultimately worked. It wasn't generating the correct url because I aslo wasn't specifying the selfLink to be my 'url' field. Thanks for the idea.